# No expected error with axios and express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I am using directions to make a request for third party APIs from my API. However, I am receiving an empty document as a return.

```
module.exports = app => {

    const servicesToll = (req, res) => {

        var obj

        try {
            console.log("'/test' call");
            axios.post('MyUrl')
                .then(res => {
                    obj = res.data

                    console.log(obj)
                    res.status(200).json(res.data)
                })
                .catch(err => res.send(err));

        } catch (err) {
            console.error("GG", err);
            console.log("I get error")
        }
    }
    console.log("I pass")
    return { servicesToll }
}
```

This way, I am not having the console return with the message: "I pass" and neither the expected object.

It is worth mentioning that console.log (obj) returns me exactly what I am expecting to receive.

```
app.route('/api')
        .get(app.api.modulos.servicesToll)
```

The console prints:

'/test' call

{
  access_token: 'YFns9SsMILak0aE9dRbqX0aw5UlFq9',
  expires_in: 86400,
  token_type: 'Bearer',
  scope: '',
  refresh_token: 'yTAY78b08Cz15brNK925IheNf7phwX'
}

Comment: FWIW your "I pass" console message is a false positive, as soon as `axios` sends the console log message will be written, this line will always run, even on a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix is:

```
.then(response => {
                    // obj = res.data

                    console.log(response.data)
                    res.status(200).json(response.data)
                })
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the code in your question?

Comment: This is the exact same code. You just changed the response variable name.

Comment: Yes but, it work. Apparently, I was using 2 nested requests. Thus, using the same name for variables, under-enrollment was taking place. I apologize if I'm making a mistake.